# What kind of spade connector is this?

Tags: connector

I need to replace a plug on a mains powered device.  It uses a specialised connector (to make it difficult for hobbyists, I guess) so I want to replace it with a standard mains plug.  Unfortunately the cable connects to the PCB using some kind of spade/Faston connector, but there are millions of different variants of these and I have no idea which parts to buy!  Does anyone know what it might be, from the photo below?  It's kind of hard to get a good view, so let me know if a particular angle would help.  The plastic cover is 9mm wide, and the metal receptacle is about 7mm wide.  The device is rated at 24A, so I'm not sure if that means there is a special high-power variant needed.

Any ideas?

[image: In housing]
[image: Alternate view]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's generally only two important variables in spade connectors:

1. **Blade** (not socket) width (the thickness may vary as well, but it should be prescribed by whatever the width is),
2. and if it's on a wire (versus a board), wire gauge it accepts.

Measure the blade width (I've only ever seen them specified in inch sizes, 0.187, 0.250...), and see if there's a good match on some parts catalogs ([here's](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=1442842) the Digi-Key category).  After that, pick the one that fits a wire gauge that will safely carry your current.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up getting a spade connector of the given width and this did indeed fit and works well.  It seems the weirdness of this connector was simply to make it easy to connect and disconnect - you can push in on the middle part to slide it off with no effort at all, and indeed the plastic cover does this for you when you try to pull it away from the connector.