# Symbols on aux sockets for old hifi

Tags: audio, connector, pinout

I have an old communist era E.European 'hifi' which I would like to connect a turntable too.  There are three DIN socket inputs on the amp, and I assume one of them must be able to receive the phono connection.  One of them seems to be magnetic tape, but I've no idea about the others (possibly different types of phono cartridge?).

I've attached a photo.

If anyone recognises these, please could you tell me:

- **What the two symbols mean**
- **If poss, a pinout for the DIN connector (so I can rewire my 2-RCA connector turtable to fit)**

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: @Leon: There are also plenty of similar examples in the related list, eg: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/what-kind-of-spade-connector-is-this

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/DIN_connector

Comment: @UpTheCreek the question you linked to is at least remotely related to electronics design as someone might be trying to figure out what the connector is called to use in their design. This question seems like pure consumer electronics.

Comment: @Kellenjb - did you read it?  He was replacing a power plug! There was no 'design'.  Not really any different to my question.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Actually... Did you read it? He said "It uses a specialised connector (to make it difficult for hobbyists, I guess)" This led me to believe he was doing some hardware hacking of a device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From left to right:

- Turntable pickup, magnetic (a.k.a. dynamic).
- Turntable pickup, crystal (a.k.a. piezo).
- Tape recorder.

See here for pinout: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Analog_audio